# Cucumber app with gradle runs fine locally but fails on Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, cucumber-jvm

When i run my cucumber based project it behaves as though it cannot find the Steps classes - I can tell because the log on Jenkins is offering code snippets for implementation.

I'm using Gradle and I know there are issues with cucumber-jvm.

The relevant part of the build file:

```
task cucumber(type: JavaExec) {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
    classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    args = ['-f', 'pretty', '--glue', 'steps', 'src/test/resources']
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
}
```

I can't see why running the same command (./gradlew clean cucumber) via Jenkins fails?

Here's the output from Jenkins:

```
+ ./gradlew -Dapk=/Users/rakesh/workspace1/AcmeApp_4_10_Tiles/bin/AcmeApp_4_10_Tiles.apk clean cucumber
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:assemble
:compileTestJava
:cucumber
Feature: Thrid party request for the Landing page.
  TODO: additional requests for box connection
...

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^the user chooses not to login$")
...

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.074 secs
$ /Users/rakesh/Apps/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect emulator-5812
[android] Stopping Android emulator
[android] Archiving emulator log
$ /Users/rakesh/Apps/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb kill-server
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant details on the failure (exact error message, stack trace, Gradle version, etc.).

Comment: there is no error. When cucumber doesn't find the steps it prints out sample code which is what its doing. The version of gradle is 1.9.

Comment: do I have to install the Jenkins gradle plugin even if I want to use the wrapper?

Comment: Jenkins Gradle plugin is optional (with or without wrapper).

Comment: yes, i installed the plugin but it made no difference.

Comment: i'm beginning to suspect that the 'hack' to get Gradle and cucumber working together doesn't work when using the gradle wrapper and Jenkins

Comment: It's unlikely that the problem is related to the Jenkins plugin or the wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to mention that sometimes this problem occurs,if there are dependencies missing in build.gradle.

In my case,the following statement was missing in main task in build.gradle..

```
dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
```

Adding this,resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and it had nothing to do with cucumber, gradle or Jenkins! I had renamed the steps classes (case change) which completely confused subversion and the java step classes were actually missing!!